# Understanding Skip gram model output

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, word2vec

If the all weight matrices between the hidden and output layer in Skip gram Word2vec model are the same, how are the outputs different one from another?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I was trying to understand skip-gram this week. I went through which seemed to be the entire Internet without finding an answer. Fortunately I was able to figure it out.

Firstly, the outputs you mentioned in your question **are indeed the same**. You are right about that. But it still makes sense, because the reason we have say **n** output vectors, is that we have n words in the skip-gram window. Each output is going to be compared with a different word in this window, and we are going to compute their errors individually. Then we update the matrices with back-propagation.

I strongly recommend you to read this article: [word2vec Parameter Learning Explained](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.2738.pdf). It will explain all your problems concerning the basics of word2vec.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, as uglybachelor has answered the outputs are the same. As an addition there is a simple example at https://iksinc.wordpress.com/tag/skip-gram-model/ which looks like this (lower precision used):

```
# skip-gram learning example

import numpy as np

wi = np.array([[-0.094, -0.44, 0.31], [-0.491, -0.23, 0.065], [0.07, 0.17, -0.36], [0.1, 0.46, 0.08], [-0.23, -0.15, -0.04], [0.41, -0.19, -0.44], [0.18, 0.09, 0.28], [-0.05, 0.49, 0.26]])
wo = np.array([[0.02, 0.48, 0.43, 0.37, -0.36, -0.12, 0.27, -0.35], [-0.37, 0.42, -0.26, -0.15, 0.03, 0.35, -0.14, 0.13], [0.42, 0.36, 0.47, -0.02, -0.42, -0.44, 0.27, -0.45]])

xk = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
ht = np.dot(xk, wi)    
u0 = np.dot(ht, wo)
yk = np.exp(u0) / np.dot(np.exp(u0), np.exp(u0).transpose())

print yk
```

which yields

```
[[ 0.14522021  0.09623482  0.11615102  0.11297892  0.15114373  0.12464769 0.12064487  0.1466973 ]]
```

The differences between yk and the respective truth vectors is then being backpropagated to update the weights wi and wo.